# Hosted Build: Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2+

Tags: android, azure-devops, visual-studio-cordova

Any idea on how to add another version to the Hosted build machine (Visual Studio Team Services / TACO)?
I'm trying to run something like:

```
$ANDROID_HOME = $ENV:ANDROID_HOME
'y' | & "$ANDROID_HOME\tools\android" update sdk --no-ui --force --filter extra-google-google_play_services
```

but got this error:

```
SDK Manager: failed to install -= Warning ! =- A folder failed to be moved. On Windows this typically means that a program is using that folder (for example Windows Explorer or your anti-virus software.) 
Please momentarily deactivate your anti-virus software or close any running programs that may be 
accessing the directory 'C:\java\androidsdk\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services'.
```

My original error was this, but maybe there is a different way to do this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. BUILD FAILED * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2+.
     Versions that do not match:
         8.4.0
         8.3.0
         8.1.0
         7.8.0
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
         file:/C:/java/androidsdk/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/java/androidsdk/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
         file:/C:/java/androidsdk/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
```

Answer (score 0):

With Hosted Build Agent, you can only run the build with the software that is already installed on the agent. There isn't any way to install any other software/version on it.

> Q: Does your build depend on [software](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software) other than this software that is
>   installed on hosted build resources?
>
> A: No. Then you can use the hosted pool.

If your build need to use any other software, you need to [deploy your own build agent.](https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows)